# Asp.net Web form Date picker selection for bundling

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my bundleConfig.cs

```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js").Include(
                "~/Scripts/moment.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js",
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/formValidation.js",
                "~/Scripts/r.js",
                "~/Scripts/alertify.js",
                "~/Scripts/select2.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/toggles.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/footable.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"));
```

and css in Bundle.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<bundles version="1.0">
  <styleBundle path="~/Content/css">
    <include path="~/Content/bootstrap.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/jquery.dataTables.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/Site.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/select2.min.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/formValidation.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/toggles.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/toggles-all.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/toggles-full.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/toggles-modern.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/alertify.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/alertif_theme_default.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/footable.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/tooltipster.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/themes/tooltipster-light.css" />

  </styleBundle>
</bundles>
```

referenced in master page.
Both `"bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" and "jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"` has date picker. when ever using date time picker in aspx page i use

```
  $('#txtSaleDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        maxDate: "0d",
       // format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    });
    $('#txtDeliveryDate').datepicker({
        dateformat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        minDate: "0d"
       // format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    });
```

But is hows the one from jQuery UI's date picker. But i want to use bootstrap-datetimepicker in my project. How to use it?????

Comment: Which exact bootstrap date picker package are you using?

Comment: i have both jQuery UI and  bootstrap referenced in project. so i want to specific bootstrap-datetimepicker to use in project

Comment: If you have two includes that have functions with the exact same name, last one loaded wins.  In other words, swap load order of bootstrap.datepicker and jquery.ui

Comment: @Bindrid not working because of bundling.

Comment: would jQuery.noConflict be of help?